# Is there any way to save only one property of an Entity with Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Because the Datastore is shared across multiple versions of an application in App Engine, I'm looking into a way for saving only certain properties of an Entity.

Let's say I have the following class in version 1 of my app:

```
@Entity
public class ThingA {
   @Id private Long id;
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
}
```

But in version 2, I changed this class to be:

```
@Entity
public class ThingA {
   @Id private Long id;
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
   private String field3;
}
```

The problem with saving the whole entity is that every time ThingA is saved on version 1 of the application, it sets "field3" to null.

It would be awesome if there's a way to save only certain fields on ThingA instead of the whole entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question after Googling a little bit more: The Datastore do not support partial updates to an entity. So that's it.